# Develop Locally with a remote repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, xampp

Hi I just wanted to check before I start researching version control.
Would It work out to develop sites locally using xampp and then svn the files to a remote repository? 
Also, is tortoisesvn a different version of svn or do the two things work together?

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It's great that you are looking to use version control, and SVN is a very good option.  If your server is running Windows, I would recommend http://www.visualsvn.com/server/.
- TortoiseSVN is a Windows Explorer-integrated client for SVN, so the two work together.  In fact, you can version control any file types through Windows Explorer.

Comment: And Is it feasible to develop locally using xampp and then commit my changes to a remote server?

Comment: Sure, in most cases SVN server is on a remote server.  On multi-developer teams, it is good to develop locally and commit to a common SVN server.

Comment: Great thanks for the feedback, I guess I have something new to learn.

Comment: Just one final thing. do I have to install svn on my computer or is enough that it is installed and set up on the remote repository?

Comment: @Andrew - You will need to have some SVN client installed (like TortoiseSVN if you use Windows).  The SVN server itself does not have to be installed on your local computer as long as it is hosted somewhere.  A good book for getting familiar with SVN is at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/  HTH